# How to write a mathematical expression without going outside the page margin?

Tags: equations

I am writing a mathematical expression in IEEE transaction 2 column format. But the problem is that it is going out of the page margin. This is my MWE:

```
\begin{align}
\hspace{-5mm}
F_{X}(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1- \hspace{-1mm}\text{exp}{\left(-\frac{\gamma_{th}\left(\left(1-\z_{h}^{2(n-1)}\right)\sigma_{h}^2+z_{h}^{2(n-1)}\sigma_{e_{h}}^2+\frac{1}{\bar{\gamma}}\right)}{z_{h}^{2(n-1)}\sigma_{h}^2}\right)},B_m=0\\ 
1-\hspace{-1mm}\text{exp}{\left(-\frac{\gamma_{th}\left(\left(1-z_{\mu_m}^{2(n-1)}\right)\sigma_{\mu_m}^2+z_{\mu_m}^{2(n-1)}\sigma_{e_{\mu_m}}^2+\frac{1}{\bar{\gamma}}\right)}{z_{\mu_m}^{2(n-1)}\sigma_{\mu_m}^2}\right)},B_m=1
\end{cases}
\end{align}
```

What changes do I need to do so as to fit this expression properly.

Any help in this regard, will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `\hspace{-1mm}\text{exp}` should be `\exp` don't use `\text` to get a math operator. It would be helpful if your example was complete so we could run it and see the problem (in particular the column width the class uses(

Comment: Ok...I replaced $\hspace{-1mm}\text{exp}$ with $\exp$ but still going outside...

Comment: yes that wasn't likely to change much but without knowing how wide the column is hard to suggest what to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd exploit the fact that the big fraction can be reused:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-3]
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}[t]
&F_{X}(x) = \textstyle
1-\exp\left(
    -\frac{
      \gamma_{th}\left(
        (1-z_{\alpha(m)}^{2(n-1)})
        \sigma_{\alpha(m)}^2+z_{\alpha(m)}^{2(n-1)}
        \sigma_{e_{\alpha(m)}}^2+\frac{1}{\bar{\gamma}}
      \right)
     }{
       z_{\alpha(m)}^{2(n-1)}\sigma_{\alpha(m)}^2
     }
   \right)
\\
&\text{where }\alpha(m)=\begin{cases} h & B_m=0\\ \mu_m & B_m=1 \end{cases}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note `\exp` instead of `\text{exp}`. Don't use `align` for single line displays.

I added `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`, otherwise the typesetting would mix Times for text and Computer Modern for math, which don't really go along.

Comment: Ok...Very nice solution...Thank you so much..